# C++ Iterator Pipelining Designs

Tags: c++, design-patterns, pipeline

Suppose we want to apply a series of transformations, `int f1(int)`, `int f2(int)`, `int f3(int)`, to a list of objects.  A naive way would be

```
SourceContainer source;

TempContainer1 temp1;
transform(source.begin(), source.end(), back_inserter(temp1), f1);
TempContainer2 temp2;
transform(temp1.begin(), temp1.end(), back_inserter(temp2), f2);

TargetContainer target;
transform(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(), back_inserter(target), f3);
```

This **first** solution is not optimal because of the extra space requirement with `temp1` and `temp2`.  So, let's get smarter with this:

```
int f123(int n) { return f3(f2(f1(n))); }
...
SourceContainer source;
TargetContainer target;
transform(source.begin(), source.end(), back_inserter(target), f123);
```

This **second** solution is much better because not only the code is simpler but more importantly there is less space requirement without the intermediate calculations.

However, the composition `f123` must be determined at compile time and thus is fixed at run time.

How would I try to do this efficiently if the composition is to be determined at run time?  For example, if this code was in a RPC service and the actual composition--which can be any permutation of any subset of `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`--is based on arguments from the RPC call.

Comment: +1 I'd love to see what people come up with.

Comment: You know that you can `transform` in place, right?

Comment: In this example, I used `SourceContainer` and `TargetContainer`, but the iterators could have come from input-stream and output-stream, which cannot be transformed in place.

Comment: @Crazy: it definitely depends on the types...

Comment: @Matthiew - it actually doesn't.  A semantically correct assignment operator is a requirement of any type used in a container in 03.  Assignment or move in 0x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Working version at http://ideone.com/5GxnW . The version below has the ideas but does not compile. It supports run time type checking, and run time function composition.

The idea is to define a generic (unary) function class, and a way to compose them with run time type checks. This is done with a combination of `boost::any`, `boost::function` and the type erasure idiom.

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>


template <typename T>
struct identity
{
    T operator()(const T& x) { return x; }
};

struct any_function
{
    template <typename Res, typename Arg>
    any_function(boost::function<Res, Arg> f)
    {
        impl = make_impl(f);
    }

    boost::any operator()(const boost::any& x)
    {
        return impl->invoke(x);
    }

    static any_function compose(const any_function& f,
                                const any_function& g)
    {
        any_function ans;
        ans.impl = compose_impl(f.impl, g.impl);
        return ans;
    }

    template <typename T>
    static any_function id()
    {
        using boost::function
        return any_function(function<T(T)>(identity<T>()));
    }

    template <typename Res, typename Arg>
    boost::function<Res(Arg)> to_function()
    {
        using boost::function;
        return function<Res(Arg)>(to_function_helper(impl));
    }

private:
    any_function() {}

    struct impl_type
    {
        virtual ~impl_type() {}
        virtual boost::any invoke(const boost::any&) = 0;
    };

    boost::shared_ptr<impl_type> impl;

    template <typename Res, typename Arg>
    static impl_type* make_impl(boost::function<Res(Arg)> f)
    {
        using boost::function;
        using boost::any;
        using boost::any_cast;

        class impl : public impl_type
        {
            function<Res(Arg)> f;

            any invoke(const any& x)
            {
                const Arg& a = any_cast<Arg>(x);
                return any(f(a));
            }

        public:
            impl(function<Res(Arg)> f) : f(f) {}
        };

        return new impl(f);
    }

    impl_type* compose_impl(boost::shared_ptr<impl_type> f,
                            boost::shared_ptr<impl_type> g)
    {
        using boost::any;
        using boost::shared_ptr;

        class impl : public impl_type
        {
            shared_ptr<impl> f, g;

            any invoke(const any& x)
            {
                return g->invoke(f->invoke(x));
            }

        public:
            impl(const shared_ptr<impl>& f,
                 const shared_ptr<impl>& g)
                : f(f), g(g)
            {}
        };

        return new impl(f, g);
    }

    struct to_function_helper
    {
        template <typename Res, typename Arg>
        Res operator()(const Arg& x)
        {
            using boost::any;
            using boost::any_cast;

            return any_cast<Res>(p->invoke(any(x)));
        }

        to_function_helper(const boost::shared_ptr<impl>& p) : p(p) {}

    private:
        boost::shared_ptr<impl> p;
    };
};
```

Now, let's use standard algorithms and do this (this even works on empty sequences):

```
// First function passed is evaluated first. Feel free to change.
template <typename Arg, typename Res, typename I>
boost::function<Res(Arg)> pipeline(I begin, I end)
{
    return std::accumulate(begin, end, 
        any_function::id<Arg>,
        std::ptr_fun(any_function::compose)
    ).to_function<Res, Arg>();
}
```

and use the following to apply it

```
std::vector<any_function> f;
std::vector<double> v;
std::vector<int> result;

std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), 
    result.begin(), 
    pipeline<double, int>(f.begin(), f.end())
);
```

You can even use `boost::transform_iterator`

```
typedef boost::transform_iterator<
    boost::function<double, int>, 
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator
> iterator;

boost::function<double, int> f = pipeline<double, int>(f.begin(), f.end());
std::copy(iterator(v.begin(), f), iterator(v.end(), f), result.begin());
```

Comment: Nice C++ code emphasizing the spirit of STL.  Learned a few things as well, including local classes and use of boost::any to simulate dynamic types in C++.

Comment: Great trick with `identity`. We have transformation monoid if we want it. Did you invent it yourself?

Comment: @Oleg: The `accumulate` algorithm is a little like `fold` in functional languages, and it needs a starting value. We are indeed working on the function level here, something C++ is particularly verbose at.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T>
class compose {
    typedef T (*f)(T);

    f first_func;
    f second_func;

public:

    compose(f one,f two) :
        first_func(one),
        second_func(two)        
    {}

    T operator()(T const &input) {
        T temp = first_func(input);
        return second_func(temp);
    }
};

#ifdef TEST

int f(int x) { return 8 + x; }
int g(int x) { return 2 * x; }
int h(int x) { return x * x; }

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    compose<int> x(f, g);
    compose<int> y(g, f);

    std::cout << x(6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << y(6) << std::endl;

    typedef int (*func)(int);

    func funcs[] = {f, g, h};

    compose<int> z(funcs[atoi(argv[1])], funcs[atoi(argv[2])]);
    std::cout << z(6);

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

With C++0x, we should be able to use `auto` to eliminate having to specify the argument/return type. For the moment I've assumed they're the same, though in theory, you might like the ability to include conversions in the mix.

Comment: Is there a variadic version of this that works with functors?

Comment: I think the OP is looking for runtime composition, which adds a level of complexity to the solution.

Comment: @kirakun: I've never written one, but I don't see any reason it couldn't be written. This code is old enough that at the time, using a template at all was pushing the limits of compiler capabilities.

Comment: @fbrereto - this solution can be used during runtime.  The only part that has to be known during compile time is the parameter and return type(s).

Comment: @fbrereto: I've added a demonstration of this doing run-time composition. @Crazy Eddie is exactly correct: all you need at compile time is the parameter/return type. If you wanted to badly enough, you could (theoretically) define an `and` and a `not`, and compose anything else you wanted from them... :-)

Comment: @Jerry: You can't chain these, which is a severe limitation.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Quite true -- as it stands, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a functor instead of function and pass needed transform functions into functor's constructor

something like

```
typedef int (*FunctionType)(int);

class Functor
{
    FunctionType m_f1;
    FunctionType m_f2;
    FunctionType m_f3;
public:
    Functor(FunctionType f1, FunctionType f2, FunctionType f3):
      m_f1(f1), m_f2(f2), m_f3(f3)
    {}
    int operator()(int n)
    {
        return (*m_f1)((*m_f2)((*m_f3)(n)));
    }
};

// ...

transform(source.begin(), source.end(), back_inserter(temp1), Functor(f1,f2,f3));
```

if you need variable number of functions then change `Functor` constructor signature to use vector of functions and fill that vector before calling transform.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef int (*f_t)(int);

int f1(int a) { return a + 1; }
int f2(int a) { return a * 2; }
int f3(int a) { return a * a; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<f_t> ff = {f1, f2, f3};
    std::vector<int> source = {1, 2, 3, 4}, target;

    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(target)
    , [&](int a) { for (f_t &f : ff) a = f(a); return a; });

    // print target
    std::copy(target.begin(), target.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int,char>(std::cout,"\n"));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice if C++0x could be deployed in production today.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Just</strike> define an iterator that does what you want:

```
template<typename T>
struct source
{
    virtual source<T>& operator++(void) = 0;
    virtual T operator*(void) = 0;
    virtual bool atend() = 0;
};

struct source_exhausted
{
};

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const source<T>& comparand, const source_exhausted&)
{ return comparand.atend(); }

template<typename T>
bool operator!=(const source<T>& comparand, const source_exhausted&)
{ return !comparand.atend(); }

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const source_exhausted&, const source<T>& comparand)
{ return comparand.atend(); }

template<typename T>
bool operator!=(const source_exhausted&, const source<T>& comparand)
{ return !comparand.atend(); }

template<typename T, typename iterT, typename endT>
struct source_iterator : source<T>
{
    iterT m_iter;
    endT m_end;
    source_iterator(iterT iter, endT end) : m_iter(iter), m_end(end) {}

    virtual source<T>& operator++(void) { ++m_iter; return *this; }
    virtual T operator*(void) { return *m_iter; }
    virtual bool atend() { return m_iter == m_end; }
};
template<typename T, typename iterT, typename endT>
auto make_source_iterator(iterT iter, endT end) -> source_iterator<decltype(*iter), iterT, endT>
{
    return source_iterator<decltype(*iter), iterT, endT>(iter, end);
}
template<typename TContainer>
auto make_source_iterator(TContainer& c) -> source_iterator<typename TContainer::value_type, decltype(c.begin()), decltype(c.end())>
{
    return source_iterator<typename TContainer::value_type, decltype(c.begin()), decltype(c.end())>(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template<typename TIn, typename TOut, typename TXform>
struct source_transformer : source<TOut>
{
    source<TIn>& m_src;
    TXform const m_f;
    source_transformer( source<TIn>& src, TXform f ) : m_f(f), m_src(src) {}

    virtual source<TOut>& operator++(void) { ++m_src; return *this; }
    virtual TOut operator*(void) { return m_f(*m_src); }
    virtual bool atend() { return m_src.atend(); }
};
template<typename TIn, typename TOut, typename TXform>
auto make_source_transformer(source<TIn>& src, TXform f) -> source_transformer<TIn, decltype(f(*(TIn*)0)), TXform>
{
    return source_transformer<TIn, decltype(f(*(TIn*)0)), TXform>(src, f);
}
```

Comment: @kirakun auto and -> in Ben Voigt's posts is alterate syntax for return types. So `int foo() { /* body */ }` can be written as `auto foo() -> int { /* body */ }`

Comment: @JoakimThorén: Importantly, while any old syntax (leading) return type can be transformed to a trailing return type, the reverse is not straightforward.  I'm using trailing return types here because the parameters are in scope, and they would not be for old syntax return types.